# vb.net create sqlite database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

What I have done so far and what I think is missing or what is WRONG in my limited knowledge
FIRST and Foremost I have spent a week reading before I wrote any of this code
I have created DB in JavaFX and VB 6 but this is a VB.Net Project

Extensions I downloaded System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.113.1 and installed I see dll files in the Debug folder but I do not see SQLite.Core in my installed Extensions

We are working on a W 7 64 bit with VS 2019 v 16.6.3

My Code includes two concepts I have tried one is active the other is commented out

I am trying to name the DB "Word.db" and all I get for a name in the Debug folder is "dbName" no matter which concept I use
I am assuming this location for the DB will permit me to make and EXE file that will include the DB

My makeDB Sub when the app runs the second time after creating the DB should execute the code below the Else statement It does not execute
Because this post has multiple issues no single question will fix this attempt to create and name a DB

```
Public Class frmStart

'Dim dbName As String = "Word.db"
Dim connStr As String = "Data Source={0};Version=3;"
Dim conn As SQLiteConnection
Dim cmd As SQLiteCommand
Private Sub frmStart_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'connectionString = String.Format(connectionString, configDb)
    'connStr = String.Format(connStr, dbName)
    connStr = String.Format(connStr, "Word.db")
    makeDB()
End Sub

Public Sub makeDB()
    'If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(dbName) Then
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("Word.db") Then
        Try
            conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=dbName;Version=3;")
            conn.Open()
            tbMessage.Text = "Database Created"
        Catch ex As Exception
            tbMessage.Text = "Database NOT Created"
        End Try
        conn.Close()
    Else
        btnCreate.Visible = False
        btnToFormTwo.Visible = True
        tbMessage.Text = "Make Table"
    End If
End Sub<br/>
```

Yes I have `Imports System.Data.SQLite`
I have noticed the DB is under the x86 folder and not under the x64 folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because

```
conn = New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=dbName;Version=3;")
```

dbName is a string, not the string (name) you declared.

You should use `"Data Source=" & dbName & ";Version=3;"` instead or the thing you made previously.

```
Public Class frmStart
Dim dbName As String = "Word.db"
Dim connStr As String = "Data Source={0};Version=3;"
Dim conn As SQLiteConnection
Dim cmd As SQLiteCommand

Private Sub frmStart_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connStr = String.Format(connStr, dbName)
    makeDB()
End Sub

Public Sub makeDB()
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(dbName) Then
        Try
            conn = New SQLiteConnection(connStr)
            conn.Open()
            'tbMessage.Text = "Database Created"
        Catch ex As Exception
            'tbMessage.Text = "Database NOT Created"
        End Try
        conn.Close()
    Else
        'btnCreate.Visible = False
        'btnToFormTwo.Visible = True
        'tbMessage.Text = "Make Table"
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Also, project packages and visual studio extensions are two different things, you added an sqlite package to you project, not an extension to vs.

Comment: How do I see that the package was installed ? Other than packages.config

Comment: @Vector Tools> Nuget... > Manage... > Installed

Comment: Why does it show a green down arrow beside Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core I did not install it I installed System.Data.SQLite.Core ONLY I guess my OCD is kicking in ha ha